# Mapping a read-only file in memory and track changes using WRITE_WATCHES doesn't work

Tags: windows, memory, bigdata

I want to map a file (actually a set of files) in memory in such a way that the contents of the files are not updated when the memory is changed.  This can normally be achieved by doing the following Windows calls (omitted some arguments):

```
auto fileHandle = CreateFile (...,GENERIC_READ,...);
auto mapHandle  = CreatefileMapping(fileHandle,...,PAGE_WRITECOPY,...);
auto memory     = MapViewOfFile(mapHandle,FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_COPY,...);
```

To be able to check which memory has been changed I want to make use of the `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` flag, but you cannot pass this to the `MapViewOfFile` function.

An alternative could be to explicitly reserve the memory using `VirtualAlloc` and pass `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` to this call, and pass the reserved address to `MapViewOfFile`, but that fails because you cannot map a view into memory that has already been reserved.

Since Windows 10 Redstone 4, you can use `VirtualAlloc2` and reserve the memory using `MEM_RESERVE_PLACEHOLDER`.  Then the function `MapViewOfFile3` can be used to map the view into the address (using the `MEM_REPLACE_PLACEHOLDER` flag).  Although this should probably work, I am already blocked by the call to the `VirtualAlloc2` method, as passing `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` to it, as it fails with error 87 (invalid arguments).

Purpose of the whole construction is to map a large (tens or hundreds of gigabytes) into memory in a read-only way (I don't want to modify the input files and I don't want to explicitly read the complete files since this might just copy the file to the pagefile (pagefile.sys)), and I want to track which memory pages have been changed while the application is running so I can copy the changed pages to another location.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you noticed that the doc for [`VirtualAlloc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) says that `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` must always be combined with `MEM_RESERVE`...? And you would then need to add `MEM_RESERVE_PLACEHOLDER` as well? Even more worriesome is that unlike that doc page, the `MEM_WRITE_WATCH` flag is not mentioned at all for [`VirtualAlloc2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2), so maybe it's not allowed.

Comment: @Glenn, yes I noticed that.  In the mean time I approached the original problem in a different way, because I concluded that I could never get this working.  I would have hoped that OS'es like Windows and Linux would have a extensive API into their page-table system so you can handle virtual memory the way you want, but apparently most of the stuff is not accessible and we remain stuck with the limited functionality of VirtualAlloc, MapViewOfFile, … and their limited set of flags.

Comment: More speculation on this... I think MEM_WRITE_WATCH is a red herring here. What you want to do, for what you describe, I think, is PAGE_WRITECOPY in the protect flags instead. And then, like the answer on this page said, query the state of the page later to see if if got demanded, in which case that’s your answer.

Comment: @Glenn, if the target would be to make a copy the first time memory is changed, I would completely agree.  But in this case, I want to know the pages that have been changed.  And a minute later, I want to know the pages that have been changed since 1 minute ago.  And so on.  PAGE_WRITECOPY is a one-shot approach.  Once a copy has been made, there's no way of knowing whether the page has been changed a second time.

Comment: @azmr, no, but my design changed completely since I asked this question, so it is not relevant for me anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use QueryWorkingSet and check each matching page for private page flag, this flag means copy-on-write occured.
BTW, this way you can also check for presence of breakpoints set by a debugger.
Good luck.

Comment: Nice idea.  Problem is that once the page has been changed (private as you say), it remains changed.  This is different from how WRITEWATCHES work (which can be queried and reset).

Answer (score -1):

What about using `MapViewOfFile` with `MEM_WRITE_WATCH`? Although undocumented, it seems that some of the other constants of `VirtualAlloc` are also used in the `AllocationType`.

Note however that I haven't tried this so far.

Comment: Please try to avoid the impression of saying "Me too." and of asking a question instead of answering. Ideally please [edit] this into an answer according to [aswer]. Otherwise please delete this post, if it is not meant to be an answer.

Comment: Hi, I’ve edited the answer so that it is not a “me too” anymore. I have no idea whether the answer is technically accurate, but at least it is a well-formed answer now, so no candidate for deletion. :-)